# checking rolled by image number?

Tags: javascript, css

So, I have a code that is rolling a random number from 1024 to 4096 and changing backgroundPosition to rolled number. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oeagymkq/))

```
function slide() 
{
    var x = 1;
    var y = 30;
    var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4096) + 1024); // background offset
    var zz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 14) + 0);  // number

    var clr = setInterval(function()
        {
            if(x >= z) x = 1;
            document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x+"px 0px";
            x+=y;
            y-=0.1;
            if (y<=0) 
            { 
                clearInterval(clr); 
                document.getElementById('rolledNumber').innerHTML = z; 
            }
        }
        ,10);


}
```

"z" is a random number between 1024 and 4096, how can I check what number on image it is? I tried `if (z >= 2285 && z <= 2210){var zz = 4;}`, where "zz" is a number on image, but it's not working.
Hope you guys can understand it.

Comment: `z >= 2285 && z <= 2210` I think you've got these backwards

Comment: You can't check what number is on the image unless you are able to map the offsets to the numerals, which doesn't seem to have a mathematical function, and therefore isn't calculable. You'll have to code it by hand to recognize ranges of position offsets as corresponding numbers. (Much like you've already tried to do with number 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1) `if (z >= 2285 && z <= 2210)`

is impossible.  There is no number that satisfies both "larger than 2284" AND "smaller than 2211".

2) "z" is a random number between 1024 and 4096

`var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4096) + 1024);` will actually create a random number between 1024 and 5120.  Imagine the case where `Math.random()` returns `1`.  Your result would be `1 * 4096 + 1024`, or `5120`.

3) Your background image is repeating - if you stick to one set of 15 numbers, you could access the number by mapping the pixel offset to an array.. something like this:

```
var boxWidth = 150;
var boxes = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8];

function getNumber (offset) {
    var boxNumber = Math.floor(offset / boxWidth);
    return boxes[boxNumber];
}
```

4) No one knows the application of this logic other than you, please reword your question such that it actually makes any sense and act like you've tried to find the problem yourself.

Comment: Well, I didn't really feel justified omitting an example solution, considering I had time to deduce the application of his logic and eventually understand his problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested - I figured out how to do this. I'm checking "x" value, and if it's between x and y, that means rolled number is z. Fragment of code:

```
if (x >= 410 && x <= 485){var rolledNumber = 1;}
if (x >= 335 && x <= 410){var rolledNumber = 14;}
if (x >= 260 && x <= 335){var rolledNumber = 2;}
```